# Will I be sinful for failing to convince my dad of his haram wealth, and benefiting from it?

Tags: halal-haram, work, waswasa, beard

I personally think that income earned by a barber is haram if it includes beard shaves and the like, but my father believes that it's completely halal.

Will I earn any sin for eating from his money earned from the barbershop? I'm still a teenager. I don't earn my own money yet.  Will I be sinful for consuming his haram wealth? I feel guilty for not being able to convince him of this

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to confirm that shaving beards is haram. Not all branches of islam sects agree on this. Shafis for example, says it is makrooh, not haram.

Secondly, even if it is confirmed as haram (which is doubtful), you also need to confirm that the wrong doing falls upon the customer who ordered his beard to shaved, not the barber.

People have a lot of reasons for wanting to shave beards. Some want to shave out of style. Others have skin problems or other medical conditions that dictates shaving beards. How can shaving a beard be haram if keeping the beard might cause bigger problems.